# with jQuery page does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just learning jQuery and the page with the following code does not load. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>First jQuery-Enabled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        alert("The page just loaded!");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `jquery-1.11.0.js` in the same location as this file?

Comment: and please read up this -- > https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console that way you can find small errors like this one really fast

Comment: since your just starting out I would use the link to thier latest minified file which is `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js` also you have `$("document")` which is telling query to select the tag document you mean to just use `$(document)`

Comment: Your page probably loads, but if the script is not working - as @rink.attendant.6 suggests - your page is likely going to appear blank.  Use your browser's "view source" feature and see for yourself if there is code in the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("The page just loaded!");
});
```

remove quotes from around document in jquery selector.